# Shorter construct for filtering object keys in json data using jq

Tags: json, jq

My data is a list of objects with many keys. To explore the data, I only want to look at a restricted set of keys.

```
input:
[
    {
        "field_1":123,
        "field_2":123,
        "field_3":123,
        "field_4":123,
        "field_5":123,
        ...and so on...
    },
    {
        "field_1":123,
        "field_2":123,
        "field_3":123,
        "field_4":123,
        "field_5":123,
        ...and so on...
    },
    ...many objects like this...
]
```

I want a result like:

```
[
    {
        "field_1":123,
        "field_2":123,
    },
    {
        "field_1":123,
        "field_2":123,
    },
    ...all objects like this...
]
```

I know I can do:

`jq '.[] | {field_1:.field_1,field_2:.field_2}'`

But it gets repetitive for data exploration on the command line. Is there a shortcut function available like:

`jq '.[] | filter_keys("field_1","field_2")'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a shorthand notation for that:

```
jq '.[] | {field_1,field_2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation, you might want to only include fields that exist in the objects so you'll have to do some path filtering. You could then just pass in a list of fields to be included. Or even do pattern based filtering.

```
$ jq --arg fields 'field_1,field_2' '
map(with_entries(select(. as {$key} | any($fields|split(",")[]; $key == .))))
' input.json
```

And as with any filter, they can be made into functions and saved to your `~/.jq` file to be globally available with something like this:

```
def filter_keys($keys):
    with_entries(select(. as {$key} | any($keys[]; $key == .)));
```

And using it:

```
$ jq --arg fields 'field_1,field_2' 'map(filter_keys($fields|split(",")))'
```